# Fail to execute command line "C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe" "-v" in eclipse EPIC

Tags: eclipse, perl

I am using ActivePerl and Eclipse Luna. I am trying to run Perl files through Eclipse but it's not working; it is giving following error

```
To operate correctly, EPIC requires a Perl interpreter" reason: Fail to execute command line  "C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe
```

It was working fine earlier but for the last couple of days it is showing this error. I have reinstalled Eclipse/EPIC and tried every solution I can wind on the web like changing the perl executable path, but nothing is working for me.

I can run Perl from the command line.

Comment: Can you run perl from the command line?

Comment: @simbabque Yes I can run perl from command Line.

Comment: And `C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe` exists? What is the output of `where perl`?

Comment: @Borodin Yes it exists , where perl gives "C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe".

Comment: Switch to strawberry Perl, forget everything you know about ActivePerl. Its easier that way.

Comment: @TLP can't do that, need to work on active perl only.

Comment: @TLP and I don't thing this issue is due to Active perl.

Comment: @TLP: I think I agree, but only because of bad experiences with ActivePerl and its ppm about twelve years ago. Do you know of a differential review?

Comment: @Borodin Well, just my experiences since switching from ActivePerl to Strawberry. Before, I was limited to which modules to use, if they worked and lots of little issues. After, no fuss, at all. Everything just works.

Comment: @TLP: I had pretty much the same experience, but I hoped and assumed that ActiveState had used the interim decade to improve their product. From what you say they've changed very little

Comment: Strawberry Perl is just a limited version of AP. Switching won't help

Comment: Try a different IDE. Not really a solution, but maybe helps in diagnosing. Komodo IDE has a 30 day trial. Install that, set up the Perl interpreter there and see if it works.